# Is the Hardy-Littlewood Maximal Function of Increasing Nonnegative Functions Increasing As well?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, derivatives

If we assume that the function $f$ is increasing, nonnegative and integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ can we conclude that the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of this function is increasing as well?

I am trying to prove that yes, this is in fact the case since if we let $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_2 \ge x_1$ then it follows that

$\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{x_{1}-\varepsilon}^{x_{1}+\varepsilon}|f(y)|dy-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{x_{2}-\varepsilon}^{x_{2}+\varepsilon}|f(y)|dy =\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\Big(\int_{x_{1}-\varepsilon}^{x_{1}+\varepsilon}|f(y)|dy+\int_{x_{2}+\varepsilon}^{x_{2}-\varepsilon}|f(y)|dy \Big)$

I get stuck here and I am unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\bar f(c,t):=\frac1{2t}\int_{-t}^{t}|f(x+c)|dx$, then the maximal function of $f$ is defined by $f^*(c):=\sup_{t>0}\bar f(c,t)$.

Now, if $f$ is increasing, non-negative and $b>a$ we can see easily that $\bar f(b,t)\geqslant \bar f(a,t)$ for each $t>0$. As $f^*(b)\geqslant \bar f(b,t)$ for all $t>0$ we also have that $f^*(b)\geqslant \bar f(a,t)$ for all $t>0$, and consequently $f^*(b)\geqslant \sup_{t>0}\bar f(a,t)=f^*(a)$.∎

Comment: If $f$ is strictly increasing, is it possible to prove that $f^*$ is strictly increasing as well? The $\sup$ step seems to change $>$ into $\ge$